# Matplotlib > ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not [color list]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to produce a simple scatterplot but I can't add the third column using the `c` argument. I don't know what's wrong:

```
plt.scatter(x=df['ratings'], y=df['viewership'], c=df['rating_categories'].to_list())
```

I am trying to encode the rating with 4 different categories based on value and I already mapped them with their specific colors in `rating_categories`. Rating categories is now a list:

```
>>> df['rating_categories'].to_list()

['orange',
 'lightgreen',
 'orange',
 'orange',
 'lightgreen',
 'orange',
 'lightgreen',
 'orange',
 'lightgreen',
 'lightgreen',
...
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Always getting this error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not ['orange', 'lightgreen', 'orange', 'orange' ..., ]
```

I tried this using the `color` argument, too. Doesn't work.

However, the same columns work with Seaborn's scatterplot with its `hue` argument.

Comment: What is `len(df.ratings)` and `len(df.rating_categories.to_list())`? Is the latter a list of lists or something?

Comment: according to your output, `df['rating_categories'].to_list()` is a list of lists but it must be just a list (see the extra `[` in the output)

Comment: Sorry, it is not a list of lists. I add an extra bracket while writing the question. Fixed it @Stef

Comment: @MustafaAydın their lengths are the same. In `df.rating_categories.to_list()` I am just converting the Pandas series to a regular python list

Comment: @BexTuychiev Maybe there is an unsupported color name in there. After `import matplotlib.colors as mcolors` what is the result of `pd.Index(df.rating_categories).difference(mcolors.CSS4_COLORS.keys()).tolist()`?

Comment: Empty list @MustafaAydın. No invalid color names‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: @BexTuychiev I tried with some sample data and it seems to work. Maybe version difference? I use `3.2.2`. Other than this, I'm out of ideas as to why this is happening, sorry. Maybe you can share a small sample of data that you apply this and get the error, and we can see if it is really reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Use the hex color code instead of the color name.
example `'#ff1500'` for `'red'` etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is because c requires a 2d array I think.
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html

Enclosing the series object in a list worked for me with the series object being numerical. I think this should work

```
plt.scatter(x=df['ratings'], y=df['viewership'], c=[df['rating_categories']])
```